# deskband toolbar button is not showing when IE protected mode is enabled

Tags: internet-explorer-8, c#-3.0, ieaddon, deskband

I have developed an add-on button that sends a tcp message to another process with the URL of the current tab. That's all it does

Since my experience is limited to managed code, I have used this article [Extending Explorer with Band Objects using .NET and Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx)

to create my toolbar button. Problem is that it's completely not showing when IE protected mode is enabled on Windows vista and 7.

I read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462(VS.85).aspx#wpm_elebp

and created an elevation policy with the GUID of my deskband , but still no use

Is there any way to handle this situation from a managed code perspective?

Comment: What does "completely not showing" mean specifically? Did you create a band object or a simple Command Bar button? Is your add-on listed inside Tools > Manage Addons?  (FWIW, writing IE extensibility in .NET is not recommended for reliability and performance reasons).

Comment: I created a bandobject which is a toolbar containing a splitbutton under .NET framerwork. By not showing I mean, that it's not even appearing in the toolbar or the manage-add-on, or in the view toolbars list. I have to disable the IE protected mode and restart for it to show !

Answer (score -1):

Try to install the add-on as an Administrator.
Also, see FAQ section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462(VS.85).aspx#faq about APIs that will lead to Access Denied.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Exactly -  you referred it, but doesn't seem you read it. wsock32.dll is restricted library, so linking to it will deny loading your addon into protected mode IE.